# Recibir respuesta a mensajes UDP en PHP

Tags: php, socket

Buenos días! 
Tengo el siguiente código PHP para enviar comandos por UDP:

```
function sendPacket($packet, $ip, $port){
   $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
   socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1);
   $message = '';
   foreach ($packet as $chunk){   //Esto es porque se espera un array de bytes
       $message .= chr($chunk);
   }
   socket_sendto($socket, $message, strlen($message), 0, $ip, $port);
   socket_close($socket);
}
```

Los paquetes que envío son del estilo:

```
const Ejemplo = array(0x12, 0x05, 0xb0);
```

El tema, es que para ciertos comandos, el receptor debería enviar una respuesta, un "OK", y ya le di mil vueltas y no encuentro el método para poner a la escucha. Probé haciendo un connect/bind y usar recvfrom, pero nada me funciono. Necesitaría encontrar la forma de que, usando la función anterior para enviar el comando, ponerme automáticamente a la escucha para esperar la respuesta si la hubiese, al menos por un tiempo limitado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP es un protocolo muy simple que no garantiza la recepción del mensaje y por lo tanto no mantiene estado de la conexión.  Dado que no requiere una negociación para establecer una conexión, me parece que no es necesario utilizar `socket_connect`.

Para poder recibir respuesta, es necesario asignar al socket una dirección y puerto de la máquina en la que se ejecuta el código utilizando `socket_bind`.  Es decir, tienes que indicar en que dirección y puerto esperas recibir las respuestas.

Después de enviar el mensaje con `socket_sendto` el código debería esperar un tiempo para permitir que llegue el mensaje al destino y que se envíe la respuesta.  Después de esa espera, habría que ejecutar `socket_recvfrom`, probablemente con la bandera `MSG_DONTWAIT` para evitar bloqueo en caso de que no llegue la respuesta (recuerda que UDP no garantiza la recepción de los mensajes).

Tu código debe determinar el tiempo de espera máximo y manejar las situaciones en las que no se reciba respuesta.

Comment: Debería bindear hacia la misma ip a la que envié el mensaje?

Comment: @ChristianBarcelo, no, debes asignar la IP de origen, es decir de la máquina en la que se ejecuta el código.